# Optimal Jump Between Two Polygons in Three Dimensions

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

### Problem

Given two polygons in 3D space (one containing a starting point, the other a goal point), what is the most optimal path between them where:

- We can only travel along the surface of the polygons or "jump"
- The "jump" operation is defined at the regular 4.9t^2 + vt + h where the starting velocity can be 0 (falling) or 9.8 units/second. (This is in the y direction)
- We travel at a constant speed of 10 units/second in the x/z direction
- The optimal path is defined as the shortest time spent traveling on the polygons' surface or jumping
- We know a jump is possible between the polygons
- The polygons are not overlapping when projected onto the x/z plane, but may touch (lets not worry about this case right now, one problem at a time)

### Situation

This is for a pathfinder running in 3D space using a navigation mesh (a bunch of polygons) in a hierarchical structure. This problem is a simplified version of the original in which polygons can be overlapping, height can restrict movements and jumps, or you don't always have a start and goal point on your two polygons (this jump may be in the middle of a set of undetermined jumps).

Comment: I fear you won't get a useful solution. Maybe try jumping from the center of one circle to the center of another, for starters.

Comment: Are the polygons horizontal or can they be slanted? Can the starting velocity have a horizontal component?

Comment: I guess you can have a horizontal component depending on how you look at it, as long as you always maintains a maximum horizontal speed of 10 units/second. I considered that horizontal movement separate from the jump, but I can see the horizontal movement of traveling stopping for a jump operation which has its own horizontal movement. Looking around at the topic of jumps in pathfinding, there is nothing. No papers address the subject more than suggesting basic, crude links be added to the navigation mesh. Nothing addresses the optimization of jumps as far as I can see.

Comment: The polygons can be any orientation in 3D space as long as they don't overlap when projected onto the horizontal plane and have a surface that can be traveled on (not vertical).